# How to Achieve Smooth Scrolling When Using SingleChildScrollView and Wrap Widget with a Lot of Children?

Tags: flutter

I am using a Wrap widget to wrap a bunch of cards and sometime the number of cards are high and causing the scroll to be unsmooth and sometime the app stop if the cards has images. The Wrap allows dynamic behavior across different devices size. Is there any way to solve this problem. I am wondering if I can build only the shown cards and not burden the memory with the other cards.? How to ensure smooth scrolling?

```
       SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: devWidth,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                child: Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    runSpacing: devWidth * 0.03,
                    children: myList.map<Widget>((item) {
                      return itemCard(item);
                    }).toList()),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Comment: `myList` average size is 10-100? 100-1000? more?

Comment: It varies from couples to a 1000

Comment: and cannot you use `ListView.builder` where each item is a `Wrap` widget wrapping some small (lets say 20-40) numbers of `Card`s?

Comment: I never tried it but I think it is more difficult to manage. Some rows might be half empty.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ListView.seperated() instead of Wrap

```
ListView.separated(
    itemCount: myList.length,
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext Context, int index) {
       return SizedBox(height: devWidth * 0.03);
    },
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return itemCard(myList[index]);
    },
)
```

for using multiple items per row use code below:

```
ListView.separated(
    itemCount: myList.length / 3,
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext Context, int index) {
       return SizedBox(height: devWidth * 0.03);
    },
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    int idx = index * 3;
           return Row(
              children : <Widget>[
                  itemCard(myList[idx]),
                  itemCard(myList[idx + 1]),
                  itemCard(myList[idx + 2])
              ]
           );
    },
)
```

Comment: Isn't gonna be card per row in this case right?. I want the cards with specific width to fit in a row dynamically depending on the device or browser size.

Comment: list view show items row by row and in this case only show one card per row and it fit to device width automatically

Comment: What I want is to fit cards as possible as it can in one row

Comment: you want add multiple cards in one row ?

Comment: let us say the card width is fixed at 200 px . and the device width is 600 px then I want to have 3 cards per row.. and so on

Comment: the point of using the Wrap widget is that it fits the number of cards per row based on device width and card width dynamically. Lets say you are on a browser and you minimize the window, the cards widths will be constant but the number of cards per row will change dynamically. Your answer doesn't solve the problem. number of cards per row is fixed to 3

Comment: yeah i know what you say but wrap not optimized for huge content